# Excel VBA how to find the ActiveCell Count of a Filtered Worksheet

Tags: database, vba, excel

i have a filterable contact database and a userform. What i want is 2 counters on the userform. lblSelection should give the total amount of Data Sets. While lblCount should give the position of the selected cell within the whole data set.

Something like "you are in set 45 of 300"

Now when the database gets filtered it should read for example "you are in set 6 of 67", using only the visible cells and counting the position of the selected cell within that range.

Here is the simple code i used so far:

```
Public Sub CountReset()

    'Display Count
        If ActiveSheet.FilterMode = False Then
            Me.lblCount = activecell.Row - 1
            Me.lblSelection = activecell.Offset(-1, 0).End(xlDown).Row - 1

        Else
            Me.lblCount = ????
            Me.lblSelection = Base.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count - 1
        End If

    End Sub
```

Thanks already for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll need a loop like this:

```
Public Sub CountReset()
    Dim n                     As Long
    Dim rCell                 As Range
    'Display Count
    If ActiveSheet.FilterMode = False Then
        Me.lblCount = ActiveCell.Row - 1
        Me.lblSelection = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).End(xlDown).Row - 1

    Else
        n = -1
        With Base.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            For Each rCell In .Cells
                n = n + 1
                If rCell.Row = ActiveCell.Row Then Exit For
            Next
            Me.lblCount = n
            Me.lblSelection = .Cells.Count - 1
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect! That solved it right away.. Many thanks, Rory!

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it.

```
Public Sub CountReset()

    Me.lblCount = activecell.Row - 1 ' this will be the same if it's filtered or not 

    If ActiveSheet.FilterMode = False Then

        Me.lblSelection = activecell.Offset(-1, 0).End(xlDown).Row - 1

    Else

        'assuming base is a defined table or named range ... also no need to filter it because it's already filtered
        Me.lblSelection = Base.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count - 1 

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for that fast reply Scott. The problem with this code is that it gives me the row number (-1) but not the count within. For example if i filter my list of 15 rows by one criteria. My first set will be in row 3, the 2nd set in row 9, the 3rd in row 11 etc. So using the ActiveCell.row will read 3, 9, 11 while it should read 1,2,3... Any ideas? thx again!

Comment: what defines a `set`? is there a column in the row that defines the set? or is there a list of rows that defines the set? (ie - set 1 is rows 1-3, set 2 is row 4-9 and set 3 is 10-11?

Comment: there are several possible columns to define a set. For example city, country, type of company, rating. These are used to define the filter settings. It s a combination checkboxes and text fields on the user form that define these search criteria. So one set is always only one row.